# how to denote a number that could be divisible by A but not B, both A and B are large integers

Tags: gcd-and-lcm, prime-factorization

The age numbers of four people are a sequence of natural numbers. The oldest person in these four people is not older than 30.  The product of four ages number is divisible by 2700, but not 81. How old are these four people？

My idea：
Since they are a sequence of natural numbers,
Let these four numbers are:
(x-2),(x-1), x ,(x+1)  for $ x+2 \le 30 $

$$ The product = (x-2)(x-1)x(x+1) $$
$$ =x^4 - 2x^3 -x^2 +2x $$

since the product is divisible by 2700，but not 81.
We know $$2700 = 2^2 * 5^2 * 3^3 , 81 = 3^4 $$
Thus, $$ x^4 - 2x^3 -x^2 +2x =  2^2 * 5^2 * 3^3 * z  $$
for {z | z cannot be 0，3 or any numbers that comes from 3 times a natural number｝.

i think that the solution might apply "2700 is the least common multiple of the product and ... ",I am stucked here and have no idea for the next step.

[image]

Comment: Are you asking for "what is the notation", or are you asking for "what is the next step"? These are very different questions, with very different replies.

Comment: As to notation, it's fairly standard for $v_p(n)$ to denote the order to which $p$ divides $n$, so in your case we'd have $v_3(n)=3, v_2(n)≥2, v_5(n)≥2$.

Comment: @lulu FYI, one minor point is that the [$p$-adic order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_order) function uses $\nu$, i.e., the Greek letter `\nu` (with this being used in the $\LaTeX$ type code in the Wikipedia article), instead of the letter $v$.

Comment: @JohnOmielan  Oh, thanks for that.  Always thought it was $v$ for "valuation".

Comment: @lulu Thanks for your answer. Does ' the order ' mean 'the rule'? or the arrangement ? I am confused to $v$'s meaning

Comment: Take the (unique) factorization of $n$, $n=\prod p_i^{a_i}$.  Then $\nu_{p_i}(n)=a_i$.   Thus $\nu_2(12)=2$, $\nu_5(12)=0$, $\nu_3(81)=4$, and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you’re only taking $4$ consecutive numbers, only one can be a multiple of $5$.  But $25$ divides the product, so your multiple of $5$ must be a multiple of $25$, and the only multiple of $25$ that’s less than $30$ is $25$.

You must have exactly $3$ factors of $3$ in your product.  You can only have at most two multiples of $3$ among $4$ consecutive integers, so for $27$ to divide the product, you need at least one multiple of $9$.  The only multiple of $9$ close enough to $25$ is $27$.

Since $81$ does *not* divide the product, $27$ needs to be the only multiple of $3$ among your integers.  Thus, they must be $25, 26, 27, 28$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 【You can only have at most two multiples of 3 among 4 consecutive integers】, how do you know that at most two multiples of 3？I can get it from the graph which I attached in the question, but if there are 30 or more consecutive integers ( it will take a long time to test all the situations in the graph) . how can I find that how many multiples of 3 could appear in 30 consecutive integers at most?

Comment: It’s very similar to the reason that $4$ consecutive integers can only have at most $1$ multiple of $5$.  You only get to select $4$ of the numbers and since multiples of $3$ are $3$ integers apart, there’s no room for more than two of them in a collection of $4$ *consecutive* integers.  Any set of $30$ consecutive integers will always have $10$ multiples of $3$.  Do you see why?